# Handling 504 timeouts when PATCHing fields on large file in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, csom

I am working on an azure function app that copies files from one sharepoint site to another on the same tenant. We copy the files using `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Site.CreateCopyJobs` CSOM api and then after the copy is finished we have to update sharepoint fields on the file for business reasons.

For the field updates we make a PATCH request using microsoft graph but for large files (seems to be > 500MB) the patch request times out with a 504 error after 30 seconds.

We had switched from using CSOM to graph API for similar errors. How can I ensure that fields on large files are getting updated? Is there a different API I should be calling for updating files of this size ?

Comment: Which endpoint do you call to update fields on large file?

Comment: @user2250152 we are calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/lists/{listId}/items/{listItemId}/fields`